# How to pass multiple StateObject into Environment Object in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, environmentobject

I am developing a shopping cart app . I want to determine when User is logged in that time I want to show MainView (Home view). If user is not logged in that time I am showing LoginView and it working fine when I pass the value into environmentObject but I want to another object which is Order class , which will be observable into different view. I am not sure How can I pass two `StateObject`s into one `environmentObject` to make sure order class is not destroyed or recreate it again ..

Error is here ..

```
.environmentObject(viewModel, order)
```

Here is my Main view ..

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct DemoEcommerceApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @StateObject var order = Order()

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           ContentViewOne()
                .environmentObject(viewModel, order)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Content view which has environment variable ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewOne: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                MainView()
            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewOne_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentViewOne()
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot..

[image: error]

Comment: You can’t, you can pass them both I individually but not together

Comment: ok . Is it good practice to pass it separately?

Comment: It’s the only option so…. Sure. Personally I don’t see why an AuthViewModel needs to go into the environment. Who else except for ContentViewOne needs to know if the user is logged in? I prefer nicely architected apps though I put a lot of effort into that.

Comment: normally there is just one object